# Why was excess of blood believed to cause cheerfulness, hopefulness?

Tags: physiology

> [ [Etymonline :](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sanguine) ] "blood-red," late 14c. (late 12c. as a surname),
>   from Old French sanguin (fem. sanguine),
>   from Latin sanguineus "of blood," also "bloody, bloodthirsty,"
>   from sanguis (genitive sanguinis) "blood" (see [sanguinary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sanguinary?ref=etymonline_crossreference)).
>   **Meaning "cheerful, hopeful, confident" first attested c. 1500, because these qualities were thought in medieval physiology to spring from an excess of blood as one of the four humors. [bold mine]** Also in Middle English as a noun, "type of red cloth" (early 14c.).

I know that the Ancient Greeks and Romans lacked the knowledge of modern medicine, but wouldn't they have been able to observe the following symptoms from patients with excess of blood who obviously couldn't have been "cheerful, hopeful, confident", e.g. if they fainted?

> [Due to the excess red blood cells, though, some people may eventually develop skin itchiness and redness, headaches, dizziness, shortness of breath, and numbness, tingling, burning or weakness in their hands, feet, arms or legs. Because PV causes blood to thicken and slow, it can also increase the risk of developing blood clots, which can cause a stroke.](https://newsnetwork.mayoclinic.org/discussion/blood-disorder-causes-body-to-make-too-many-red-blood-cells/)

Comment: Let's say Greeks and Romans did observe that. Since usage in this sense dates only to 1500 AD what bearing would that have on it? And why should one take a negative association instead of the one of being red in the face from liveliness and cheer as the basis for coining a word? Etymologies do not follow "natural laws", much of it is just whimsical analogies and loose associations.

Comment: I don't get why this question was downvoted, please give an explanation when you downvote so the question can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

See e.g.: James Irwin, [Galen on the Temperaments](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00221309.1947.9918106?journalCode=vgen20) (1947).

You have to follow the link from [Hippocrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocrates)’ ideas of humors, or bodily fluids, as a part of character, though the modifications of the later physician, [Galen], into a doctrine of “temperaments” as a semi-scientific study of the larger field of character study.

The Greek theory of four elements has been adopted by Hippocrates:

> Now all animals including man, are composed of two things, different in power but working together in their use, namely, fire and water.
>   [...] These elements have severally the following attributes. Fire has the
>   hot and the dry, water the cold and the moist. Mutually, too, fire has
>   the moist from water, for in fire there is moisture, and water has the
>   dry from fire, for there is dryness in water also.

He also asserts that:

> the constituents of the body to be blood, phlegm, yellow bile, and black bile.

In conclusion, we can summarize the theory with two schema:

> hot and dry equals fire,
>
> hot and moist equals air,
>
> cold and dry equals earth,
>
> cold and moist equals water.

And:

> hot and dry equals yellow bile,
>
> hot and moist equals blood,
>
> cold and dry equals black bile,
>
> cold and moist equals phlegm.

When these four humors are properly mingled the body is in a state of health; when there is a defect or an irregularity in the mixture, disease arises.

Through Aristotle, this theory is adopted by Galen:

Diseases affecting the the four humors:

> are “dyscrasia,” and contrast with the complete and harmonious mixture of the humors or “eucrasia.” But this state of ideal health rarely occurs, and the predominance of the various humors gives rise to the “temperaments” or sanguine, phlegmatic, bilious or melancholic, which though partaking of the nature of the disease, are not actually to be so called unless they produce a perversion of
>   function.
>
> The specific temperaments arise when one of the four humors is in predominance in the body and from which they are specifically derived. Thus, when examined
>   in this light the temperaments were actually more than just humors or bodily
>   fluids for they were actual conditions of the body arising out of the preponderance of their immediate specific humor as the sanguine temperament
>   from the preponderance of blood, to illustrate the point.

The sanguine temperament is associated to the humor of blood and to the quality of hot and moist.

See Galen, [On Diseases and Symptoms](https://books.google.it/books?id=hx99p9L6ep4C&pg=PA154) (Ian Johnston editor, 2006), XII.2, page 154:

> because of the aforementioned humours, even if in form they are all moist, in capacity they are not moist, for black bile is dry and cold, and yellow bile is dry and hot, whereas moist and cold is of phlegm, whilst the blood is moist and hot.

Much more difficult is to assess the relationship between temperaments (the body) and passions (the soul).

See R.J. Hankinson (editor), [The Cambridge Companion to Galen](https://books.google.it/books?id=ygBactKUkAMC&printsec=frontcover), Cambridge University Press (2009), **Ch.7**, P.Donini, *Psychology*, page 184-on:

> ‘the movements of the passions are always consequent upon the dispositions of the body’ and that ‘they are the product of temperaments of the body which are similar to them’.

Galen adopted the thesis of the Platonic origin of the tripartition of the soul into the rational (*logistikon*), the spirited (*thumoeides*) and
desiderative (*epithumetikon*), a thesis which he also attributes to Hippocrates.

Galen maintains that the Platonic location of the three parts in three distinct organs: the rational part in the brain, spirited part in the heart and desiderative part in the liver.

Galen adopt also an Aristotelic point of view: according to it the soul is the form of the body, and its parts are understood by Galen as being the forms of
the bodily organs in which each of them resides. But the form is
identical with the temperament, i.e. with the mixture of elementary
bodies or of the corresponding qualities which constitute the organ.
Thus the desiderative soul will be the form and temperament of the
liver, the spirited will be the form and temperament of the heart,
while the rational soul must consequently be the form and temperament
of the brain.

Conclusion: this seems to be the long road from *blood* to the *sanguine* temperament to a "spirited" behaviour.